# formatting "gcloud app logs tail" output for structured logs (single line of serialized JSON) in pretty text

Tags: java, json, google-app-engine, java.util.logging, structured-logging

I am trying to do structured logging simply with JUL and console handler. As mentioned in google's official documentation https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/logging#using-json I am using ***single line of serialized JSON*** with *severity* and *message* JSON keys to make logging structured and its working as expected. As a log viewer, I am able to filter logs by severity.

But when I am streaming Logs with **gcloud app logs tail** I am getting output in this weird format.

```
<JsonPayloadValue   additionalProperties: [<AdditionalProperty   key: 'thread'   value: <JsonValue   string_value: '16'>>, <AdditionalProperty   key: 'message'   value: <JsonValue   string_value: 'Time taken in smart suggest: 128 ms, Class -> servlets.xyzServlet, Method -> doPost'>>, <AdditionalProperty   key: 'timestamp'   value: <JsonValue   string_value: 'Apr 5, 2021 6:51:11 AM'>>]>
```

How can i format these json to one linear of pretty text

```
[Apr 5, 2021 6:51:11 AM] Time taken in smart suggest: 128 ms, class -> servelt.xyzServlet, Method -> doPost'
```

Comment: Do you mean to change output of `gcloud app logs tail` command? or you want to find other way to process the logs?

Comment: @vitooh currently I am processing logs by parsing the log tail output using awk parser. I just wanted to get text in pretty format. Can i change output of log tail also? what do you mean by change?

Comment: I think this could be good idea for Feature Request. Please raise on [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/getting-support#file_bugs_or_feature_requests).